# Why is monodroid/ android emulator so slow?

Tags: android, android-emulator, xamarin.android

I can't believe how slow both of these things are especially seeing that the emulator is from google and you would think they would all be about speed.

First the emulator takes like 30 seconds or more too boot up. Do any action(like moving to another screen) is laggy.

Trying to debug through VS 2010 and Monodroid is a nightmare. To from line 10 to line 11 takes like 30 seconds.

I tired using snapshot. I am using android V 2.3.3 but nothing seems to help.

I have windows 7 64bit edition.

Anyone else know how to speed things up a bit?

Comment: 1) use a recent hardware device instead of an emulator or test your logic on a different computing platform first 2) use an official android language such as java or ndk C/C++ components.

Comment: @ Chris Stratton - Option 1 can't do as I am still in evaluation mode with monodroid(plus don't have a device right now). Option 2 won't make a difference as I tried that as well and using Eclipse and Java does not speed anything up.

Comment: Depending on what you are doing you may be able to run an x86 build of android in a virtualization solution, which will be faster than emulating another process as only "special" operations have to be emulated in software.  But these builds of android are unofficial and less mature.  If your time is worth anything though, just buy a device - it doesn't have to be a *phone*.

Answer (score 2):

The emulator is slow by virtue of being an emulator: your computer is having to pretend, through a virtualization layer, to be an entirely different piece of hardware, and that means that just about every operation is going to be dramatically slower than it would be running natively. Your only real option to get better performance for testing your Android apps is to upgrade your computer (which won’t help much: emulating hardware is taxing on any system) or to run your code on an actual device.

Comment: In the OP's defense, the Android emulator is unusually slow.  I've used emulators for Windows Mobile and Blackberry development and both are sufficiently peppy ... I've even run demos for customers with them.  I would not dream of doing that with the Android emulator.

Comment: I understand that is has to do alot but like @Earl said I used Windows mobile emulator, windows 7 emulator, blackberry emulator, j2me emulators and they nowhere near this slow. I mean going from one break line to another should not take 30+ seconds, Loading a view up should not take 10+ seconds. I ran the windows 7 emulator and I can switch pages and it takes maybe a second. To load the 15 seconds. Android took 70 seconds to load  that is a difference of 55seconds.